# One-liner competition

Tags: deployment

How to participate in the annual Mathematica one-liner competition?

You can find the previous winners, blogs and announcements about this,
but no single word about how to submit one.
Asked Wolfram via twitter but got no reply.

Comment: You'll have better luck asking on the Wolfram Community site - as it stands I think this question is out of scope for this site since there's no Wolfram Language code we can help you with :)

Comment: I tried for a long time. It seems people keep it under a cloak of silence. Maybe its just for the privileged and not open for everyone.

Comment: @darksun A quick search links to a [Wolfram blog entry](https://blog.wolfram.com/2020/10/20/the-winners-of-the-2020-one-liner-competition/) which says "Although this year's Wolfram Technology Conference was virtual, that didn't stop us from running the ninth annual One-Liner Competition..." Sounds like you'll need to register for the [Wolfram Technology Conference](https://www.wolfram.com/events/technology-conference/2021/) to participate.

Comment: No, the conference just presents the winners.

Comment: @darksun Are you sure? The blog makes it pretty clear. Here's [2016](https://blog.wolfram.com/2016/11/09/the-2016-wolfram-one-liner-competition-winners/): "Could you fit the code for a fully functional game of Pong into a single tweet? One that gives you more points the more you take your chances in letting the “ball” escape? Philip Maymin did, and took first prize with that submission in the One-Liner Competition held at this year’s Wolfram Technology Conference."

Comment: @darksun And [2017](https://blog.wolfram.com/2017/11/08/what-can-you-say-in-one-line-of-the-wolfram-language-the-2017-one-liner-competition/): "The One-Liner Competition is a tradition at our annual Wolfram Technology Conference, which took place at our headquarters in Champaign, Illinois, two weeks ago. We challenge attendees to show us the most impressive effects they can achieve with 128 characters or fewer of Wolfram Language code." If you find evidence to the contrary, please let us know, but it sure looks like the One-Liner Competition is part of WTC.

Comment: For me that just says that the evaluation/presentation is done at WTC, not that only conference members can submit.

Comment: one-liner@wolfram.com (Google search gives just two sites, so its extraordinary hard to find.)